# Android java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect

Tags: java, android, http

i have problem with connecting to website.I know this is problem with connection, but i want to point that my smartphone is connected with web while testing. Sometimes my application crashes and i get this log message:

```
11-15 19:34:41.894: W/System.err(737): java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to www.money.pl/212.77.101.20 (port 80) after 3000ms
11-15 19:34:41.904: W/System.err(737):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:150)
11-15 19:34:41.904: W/System.err(737):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
11-15 19:34:41.904: W/System.err(737):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
11-15 19:34:41.914: W/System.err(737):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
11-15 19:34:41.914: W/System.err(737):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
11-15 19:34:41.914: W/System.err(737):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:77)
11-15 19:34:41.914: W/System.err(737):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
11-15 19:34:41.924: W/System.err(737):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:351)
11-15 19:34:41.924: W/System.err(737):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:86)
11-15 19:34:41.924: W/System.err(737):  at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
11-15 19:34:41.934: W/System.err(737):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:308)
11-15 19:34:41.934: W/System.err(737):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:303)
11-15 19:34:41.945: W/System.err(737):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:282)
11-15 19:34:41.945: W/System.err(737):  at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
11-15 19:34:41.945: W/System.err(737):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
11-15 19:34:41.954: W/System.err(737):  at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:512)
11-15 19:34:41.954: W/System.err(737):  at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:493)
11-15 19:34:41.954: W/System.err(737):  at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:205)
11-15 19:34:41.964: W/System.err(737):  at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:194)
11-15 19:34:41.964: W/System.err(737):  at morisson.Notowaniagieldowe.Zmienne$Cena.doInBackground(Zmienne.java:94)
11-15 19:34:41.974: W/System.err(737):  at morisson.Notowaniagieldowe.Zmienne$Cena.doInBackground(Zmienne.java:1)
11-15 19:34:41.974: W/System.err(737):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
11-15 19:34:41.974: W/System.err(737):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
11-15 19:34:41.984: W/System.err(737):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
11-15 19:34:41.984: W/System.err(737):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
11-15 19:34:41.995: W/System.err(737):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
11-15 19:34:41.995: W/System.err(737):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
11-15 19:34:42.034: W/System.err(737):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
11-15 19:34:42.034: W/dalvikvm(737): threadid=15: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409bf1f8)
11-15 19:34:42.045: E/AndroidRuntime(737): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-85
11-15 19:34:42.045: E/AndroidRuntime(737): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-15 19:34:42.045: E/AndroidRuntime(737):  at morisson.Notowaniagieldowe.Tab2Fragment$1.transformacja_ceny(Tab2Fragment.java:70)
11-15 19:34:42.045: E/AndroidRuntime(737):  at morisson.Notowaniagieldowe.Tab2Fragment$1.run(Tab2Fragment.java:91)
```

does someone know how to avoid this error?

Comment: Are you sure that you want to access www.money.pl/212.77.101.20? It looks like you are constructing the URL wrong.

Comment: Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.money.pl/gielda/gpw/akcje/").userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.80 Safari/537.36").get();